# Circuit simulator with microphone support

Tags: microphone, simulation

I am working with a circuit that consists of a condenser microphone. The circuit will filter through all sound signals except very sharp high pitch sound. But I cannot find any circuit simulator that has microphone component. I have tried CircuitLogix, QUCS, LTspice etc.

I understand that sound signals may be simulated but it would be great if this simulated component could get signals from microphone in my computer. Is there any simulator like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Multisim](http://www.ni.com/multisim/) is able to record from a microphone and use it as input signal, [but not in real-time](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/42A992A951D71B3E86257B500053B90D).

LTspice [can read from a .wav file](http://electrostud.wikia.com/wiki/Using_WAVE_files_as_input/output_in_LTSpice), in this case you can use an audio editor (like [Audacity](http://audacity.sf.net/)) to record.